# Testing arguments of the method tested

Tags: symfony, unit-testing, testing, mocking, phpunit

is it possible or good idea to test arguments of the class that has the method mocked ? 
Example :

```
class CarType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder->addEventSubscriber(new User('argument example')

    }
}
```

This is my test:

```
    public function testFormBuilder()
    {

    $builder = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

       // Test    
        $type = new CarType();

            $this->builder->expects($this->once())
                ->method('addEventSubscriber')
                ->with(
                    $this->isInstanceOf(User::class)
                );

            $type->buildForm($this->builder, []);


    }
```

This test work fine, But...
I want to know if the first argument of the `User` class is a string, but can I do in this same test?

Comment: Is the argument of `User` an harcoded value or something that is in `$options`? If you really need to check that is a string, may be the check should be done in `User` constructor through a parameter validation, then you can test it with phpunit.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to check directly because the `User` is being created directly in your code that you are testing.

However depending if the string can be retrieved via a public method of the `User` class, then you could do something like this:

```
$this->builder->expects($this->once())
            ->method('addEventSubscriber')
            ->with(
                $this->callback(function($user) {
                    if (! $user instanceof User) {
                        return False;
                    }

                    if ($user->getName() != <Expected String>) {
                        return False;
                    }

                    return True;
                })
            );
```

You can use a callback check further details of `User` instance.  You are not verifying that the string was passed to the constructor but you can check that the object is properly created.

Though this isn't the best way to go about this.  Your code is not extensible because you are not able to change the `User` class.  It would be better to pass in a `User` object to the method that gets passed on.  This would allow you have different types of `User` objects in the future.